# Best way to add existing permission to a group in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-permissions

I'm trying to add existing permissions (from auth_permission table) to an existing group (from auth_group) in Django.

In Django shell I could do this by the following code:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
my_group = Group.objects.get(name='mygroupname')
perm_change = Permission.objects.get(codename='change_specific')
my_group.permissions.add(perm_change)
```

The code above is working as expected, but how can I make it permanent? Should I modify the model or make a custom migration?

I think that migration should work fine, but I can't figure out how to do it. (There is a way to turn my shell modifications in a migration?)

Thanks.

Comment: I've managed this by using ```has_change_permission``` in the model, but verifying if a user is part of a specific group inside each permission doesn't look the correct way to do this. Based on the database structure, it makes more sense something like a configuration file or defining in migration.